# Fortran DO loop over generic set of indices?

Tags: fortran, do-loops

I have an N-dimensional dataset (say real numbers) which is stored as a 1D array with an additional dimension array which specifies the original dimensions.

In addition, the functions to deduce the 1-D index from an N-D index and vice-versa are given.

I'm trying to figure out how do I make a do-loop (or equivalent) for the generic N-dimensional index (which will be transformed to 1D index of course) from some set of limiting lower indices to a set of upper indices.
So I need an "N-dimensional" loop which **does not go over all of the values** - only a portion of the array, therefore doing the linear index of an equivalent 1D array is not relevant (at least without modifications).

This is a schematic of my problem:

```
subroutine Test(Array,Dims,MinIndex,MaxIndex)

implicit none
real   , dimension(1:), intent(inout) :: Array
integer, dimension(1:), intent(in)    :: Dims,MinIndex,MaxIndex

integer, dimension(size(Dims)) :: CurrInd
integer :: 1Dindex

! size(Dims) can be 1, 2, 3 ,..., N
! size(MinIndex)==size(MaxIndex)==size(Dims)
! size(Array)==Product(Dims)
! 1Dindex=Get1dInd(NDindex,Dims)
! NDindex=GetNdInd(1Dindex,Dims)

! How do I actually preform this?
do CurrInd=MinIndex,MaxIndex
  1Dindex=Get1dInd(CurrInd,Dims)
  <Some operation>
enddo


end subroutine
```

I figured it is possible to loop over the `Dims` array and use an inner loop but I don't manage to write the procedure down properly.

Another option that didn't work for me (maybe because I use it incorrectly?) is `FORALL`, as that requires each index to be specified separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you knew the dimensions of your arrays at compilation time you could do a series of nested `DO` loops, each of them running between pairs of components of `MinIndex` and `MaxIndex`.  Since you don't know the dimensions, that's not possible.

The easiest strategy I can think of is to loop with a single `DO` loop over all the 1D indices.  For each of them, compute the N-dimensional index, and check if it is within the bounds provided by `MinIndex` and `MaxIndex`: if it is, continue doing what you need; if it is not, discard that 1D index and go to the next one.  If the indices are sequential you may be able to do something smarter that skips blocks of indices that you know you will not be interested in.

```
do OneDindex = 1, size(Array)
   CurrInd = GetNDInd(OneDindex, Dims)
   if ((any(CurrInd<MinIndex)) .or. (any(CurrInd>MaxIndex))) cycle
   ! <Some operation>
end do
```

Note that, as far as the index manipulation is concerned, this strategy is compatible with parallelising the loop.

Also note that Fortran variables must start with a *letter*: `1Dindex` is not a valid Fortran variable name.

Comment: Thank you. This is very similar to what I had thought of eventually.

Answer (score 2):

So this is the actual procedure I ended up with.
I have verified it and hope it will be useful to you as it was for me.
(I know this is not well commented, but the question has all the details and my time is extremely short at the moment)

Also, thanks ripero for helping out!
I decided not to use the CYCLE approach as I assume the code will work more efficiently when only the actual amount of loops are performed.

```
  !-----------------------------------------------------------
  subroutine Test(Array,Rank,Dims,InitInd,FinInd)
    implicit none
    real,    dimension(1:), intent(inout) :: Array
    integer,                intent(in)    :: Rank
    integer, dimension(1:), intent(in)    :: Dims
    integer, dimension(1:), intent(in)    :: InitInd,FinInd
    !-----------------------------------------------------------    
    integer :: nOuter
    integer :: i,j, OneDInd
    integer, dimension(Rank) :: Curr
    !-----------------------------------------------------------

    ! Check how many repetition for the outer-loop
    Curr=FinInd-InitInd
    nOuter=1
    do i=2,Rank
       nOuter=nOuter*(Curr(i)+1)
    enddo

    !-----------------------------------------------------------
    ! Actual looping:
    Curr=InitInd
    do j=1,nOuter
       ! Update minor indices (>1):
       do i=1,Rank
          if (Curr(i).GT.FinInd(i)) then
             ! Update next index:
             Curr(i)=InitInd(i)
             Curr(i+1)=Curr(i+1)+1
          endif
       enddo

       ! Loop over major index:
       do i=InitInd(1),FinInd(1)
          !OneDInd=Get1dInd(Curr,Dims)
          !<operation>


          ! Advance major index:
          Curr(1)=Curr(1)+1
       enddo

    enddo

  end subroutine Test
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. Note that, in your subroutine, you only need to pass the rank explicitly if you want to be able to operate on the first rank dimensions, otherwise you can easily determine it from, e.g., the size of Dims.  Also be aware that, while you will win speed from avoiding calls to GetNDInd and operating on a smaller number of loops, in your main loop every iteration depends on the previous ones, so you will not be able to parallelise it.

Comment: In my previous comment, please s/smaller number of loops/smaller number of iterations/, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I pass the rank just to define `Curr` quickly, as I use this call many times and can calculate the rank only once for many calls. Also paralleling this was not a concern to begin with - but is definitely meaningful to whoever will use this in the future.